# Handling https schema in intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an intent filter in the Manifest which handles taps on urls, if url match filter data my application starts.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" port="8765" android:path="/mypath" />
</intent-filter>
```

Intent filter works when schema is "http" but if I change it to "https" intent filter doesn't do anything and link starts to load in a browser.

Does anybody know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add an extra data line to your filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" port="8765" android:path="/mypath" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" port="8765" android:path="/mypath" />
</intent-filter>
```